# How to list all network routes between two points and select one for transmission

Tags: linux-networking

I have a system which is connected to the internet via a Linux router.
Normally using traceroute we can check the network route the packets traveled.

Is there any tool in Linux which will list all the network routes from my system till the destination ?
Is there any way to select a particular network route from the list dynamically such that all packets from my system follow that selected route.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the dynamic nature of the Internet (Inter Network) and that you don't control the networks between the end points you can't do specify which route to follow.

You can list the routes using traceroute/mtr but they are also subject to change

Answer (score 0):

You might use *source routing* to choose which path your packets must follow... but it is unfortunately disabled on most router so unless you manage every router your packets go through, you won't be able to do it.